# Forecasting apple stock

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to create a machine learning model to forecast apple stocks, first time trying and really based most from YouTube videos. But I don't really understand the cause of the error.
I already try separated the function but that asked to reshape the arrays and use numpy arrays.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dta = pd.read_csv('aapl.csv')

dta.Date = dta.Date.apply(pd.to_datetime)
dates = np.array(dta.Date)
prices = np.array(dta.Open)

def predicted_prices(dates,prices,x):
    dates = np.reshape,(len(dates),1)

    svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
    svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C = 1e3, degree = 2)
    svr_rbf =SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
    svr_lin.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_poly.fit(dates,prices)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates,prices)

    plt.scatter(dates,prices,color='black',label='Data')
    plt.plot(dates,svr_rbf.predict(dates),color='red',label='RBF model')
    plt.plot(dates,svr_lin.predict(dates),color='green',label='Linear Model')
    plt.plot(dates,svr_poly.predict(dates),color='blue',label='Polynomial model')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_lin.predict(x)[0],svr_rbf.predict(x)[0]
predicted_prices(dates,prices,29)
```

I expect to get a graph of the forecasted values.

Error log:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-1-6870461ae560> in <module>()
 33     return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_lin.predict(x)

[0],svr_rbf.predict(x)[0]
     34 
---> 35 predicted_prices(dates,prices,29)

<ipython-input-1-6870461ae560> in predicted_prices(dates, prices, x)
     17     svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C = 1e3, degree = 2)
     18     svr_rbf =SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
---> 19     svr_lin.fit(dates, prices)
     20     svr_poly.fit(dates,prices)
     21     svr_rbf.fit(dates,prices)

C:\Users\chris\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    147         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64,
    148                          order='C', accept_sparse='csr',
--> 149                          accept_large_sparse=False)
    150         y = self._validate_targets(y)
    151 

C:\Users\chris\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    754                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
    755                     warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype,
--> 756                     estimator=estimator)
    757     if multi_output:
    758         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

C:\Users\chris\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    525             try:
    526                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 527                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    528             except ComplexWarning:
    529                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

C:\Users\chris\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    499 
    500     """
--> 501     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    502 
    503 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors that I spot (please, provide error log):

This is obviously an error

```
dates = np.reshape,(len(dates),1)
```

which should be something like:

```
dates = np.reshape(dates, (len(dates),1))
```

Also, when you fit the SVRs you are giving as X the date and as y the price. This makes the algorithm learn to predict using dates. Are you sure this is the best feature to predict the price? Maybe you should use other stocks or business indicators.

Hope this helps.

P.D: please, report a log of the error and I will be ble to help you better.

Comment: I would agree with @BCJuan, using the date as your only feature is not good practice for time series forecasting. The idea of machine learning is that, based on the similar trends in the data, you want to make a prediction of the future. And dates are unique, so there is no patterns. But you can extract features from dates, in this way a pattern could be learnt.

Comment: Thanks to both, I understand that time is not ideal to predict based on dates but I'm just starting to learn about machine learning and really trying to learn how to use it and how the coding portion of it works.

P.D: Error Log before correcting spotted errors added.